# Particular solution for auxiliary solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

[This is the question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ZFx7.png)

I have done the 1a) and b) but i got stucked at c.

For 1a ii) I  have got $Ae^{-4x} + Bx^{-4x}$

Comment: It is best to type the specific question above, rather than give a link. Your question seems to be asking about solving $x''(t) + 8x'(t) + 16x(t)=0$ with given initial conditions.  I observe that your answer to (a) should express $x(t)$ as a function of time, not as a function of $x$.  Also you need to find two linearly independent solutions and multiply one by $A$, the other by $B$, you have multiplied the same solution by both $A$ and $B$ which does not help.

Comment: After you have done that, you can elaborate on your work and on your specific challenges going forward.  Specifically, what part of the problem are you finding to be difficult? [Is it understanding that $x(t)$ should be a function of $t$?  Is it understanding how to choose $A,B$ to meet initial conditions? Is it understanding how to find two linearly independent  solutions?]

Comment: Thank you michael. I found my mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For ii 1a

$$x''+8x'+16=0$$
$$\implies r^2+8r+16=0 \implies (r+4)^2=0 \implies r=-4$$
With a double root the solution to the differential equation is
$$x(t)=Ae^{-4t}+B\color{red}{t}e^{-4t}$$
Now try to find the constants A and B with the initial conditions given
$$x(0)=1 \implies x(0)=Ae^{0}+B\times \color{red}{0 \times }e^{0}$$
For the second IC
$$x'(0)=1 $$
Differentiate the solution first $$x(t)=Ae^{-4t}+B\color{red}{t}e^{-4t}$$
$$\implies x'(t)=.........$$